# What should we do about tags on story-id questions?

Tags: discussion, tags, story-identification

Often, in posting a [story-identification](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story-identification) question, a user will add a tag that has to do with one element of a story that they remember. e.g., A story about a werewolf that tries to eat lettuce will be tagged [story-identification](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story-identification), [lettuce](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lettuce), [young-adult](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/young-adult), and [werewolf](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/werewolf). But it's not a question about werewolves - it's a question about a story that has a werewolf in it.

Should we *only* tag [story-identification](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story-identification) questions with tags that are specifically for story-id ([story-identification](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story-identification), [young-adult](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/young-adult), [novel](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/novel), [books](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/books), [short-stories](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/short-stories), etc), or have other tags as well (such as [aliens](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aliens), [computers](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/computers), [time-travel](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time-travel) etc)?

Answer (score 8):

I think that it comes down to one of the purposes for tags, namely expertise. Someone who's an expert in [werewolf](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/werewolf) is likely to have the background to answer story-identification questions about them. So yes, the tags are good in the question. If someone of them turn out to be inaccurate (the story isn't actually about werewolves, but vampires, and the querent realizes they were mistaken), we fix the tags.

Comment: OTOH, [tag:lettuce] does not exist and *should* not exist.